# sending email continously using phpmailer and aws ses

Tags: smtp, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I was using phpmailer to send emails from our ubuntu 14.04 server and we are using **AWS SES** to send emails with phpmailer. We are getting first two emails quickly but after that browser goes into a loop and didn't send emails for at least 2-3 minutes.

I need it so that phpmailer send mails continuously without going into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a solution and want to share with you guys. May be that can help someone. So, i searched for some time and didn't get any specific result.

Then i tried changing port from 25 to 587 and it works!! now mails are going continously without any break